# Maven Can't Download Its Plugins

Tags: maven, maven-3, gitlab-ci

## What I'm Using

1. Java 9
2. Maven 3
3. GitLab CI

## Situation

I have been trying get a maven build setup with CI on GitLab for my project. I need to compile my project with `mvn clean install` because I am using multiple modules.

Locally I am able to build the jars exactly how I want them. When I do `mvn clean install` it runs with no errors.

### Problem

With GitLab CI I am using the docker image `maven:3-jdk-9` since I want to use maven 3 and I am using java 9. The build with `mvn clean install` always fails because it can't download the necessary maven plugins.

*Here is the error*

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom. Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Request.
```

## What I've Tried

1. Adding a settings file with a proxy for central and building with `mvn clean install -s .m2/settings.xml` insead

*.m2/settings.xml*

```
<settings>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>maven central</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <host>repo.maven.apache.org</host>
            <port>80</port>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
```

2. Using maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 *(not sure if I did this correctly, check the comments)*
3. Creating a local GitLab CI runner
4. Using Java 9 docker image and installing maven manually

## Notes

Sorry in advance if this is a simple mistake, I am not very experienced with using maven.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nullpointer Are you talking about maven 3.7.0 or maven-compiler-plugin 3.7.0

Comment: I meant maven-clean plugin 3.0.0 .

Comment: @nullpointer How can I set it to use that version instead?

Comment: By editing the `build` section of your project's pom.xml file.

Comment: @nullpointer I have added `<plugin><artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId><version>3.0.0</version></plugin>` To my build plugins but am still getting the same error. Did I do that correctly? Sorry it won't let me format it.

Comment: The error message is the problem: `Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Request.` it means no access to central repository....This is the thing which must be fixed first...

Comment: @khmarbaise Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: I don't know, cause I don't know if you are behind a corporate firewall/proxy etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Nope, it works fine locally. I am using the public GitLab runners to do the CI so It should be fine.